# How to create a form for the rails-settings plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, settings

I have a Rails 3 App that has needs some user defined settings.  I would like to use this https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings plugin.  I have it working in the rails console.  But I am having trouble getting working in a form.  Do I use fields_for & attr_accessible?  If so I am having no luck.

I need to add settings for two Models:

For example, settings that are specific to a User,

```
user = User.find(123)
user.settings.color = :red
user.settings.color
# => :red

user.settings.all
# => { "color" => :red }
```

(The above works fine for me in the console.)

but I need to administer them through a standard web form.  I'd love to know how others are handling this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

What I did is add dynamic setters/getters to my User class as such

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_settings

  def self.settings_attr_accessor(*args)
    args.each do |method_name|
      eval "
        def #{method_name}
          self.settings.send(:#{method_name})
        end
        def #{method_name}=(value)
          self.settings.send(:#{method_name}=, value)
        end
      "
    end
  end

  settings_attr_accessor :color, :currency, :time_zone

end
```

With that, you can use "color" just like any other attribute of your User model.
Also it's very simple to add more settings, just add them to the list

Comment: Excellent answer--I was a little uncertain how to do this and this works like a charm.  Makes using rails-settings very clean--many thanks!  The gem author should post this as an example on his Github Wiki. My only change was to make the function definition and function call private.

Comment: Every time I use this in a form, like normal variables, I get: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: color, currency, time_zone`. Any ideas?

Comment: I keep getting the error "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)" when I try this out