# How to perform Rails model validation checks within model but outside of filters using ledermann-rails-settings and extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, settings

### Background

I'm using ledermann-rails-settings (https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings) on a Rails 2/3 project to extend virtually the model with certain attributes that don't necessarily need to be placed into the DB in a wide table and it's working out swimmingly for our needs.

An additional reason I chose this Gem is because of the post [How to create a form for the rails-settings plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425798/how-to-create-a-form-for-the-rails-settings-plugin) which ties ledermann-rails-settings more closely to the model for the purpose of clean form_for usage for administrator GUI support.  It's a perfect solution for addressing form_for support although...

Something that I'm running into now though is properly validating the dynamic getters/setters *before* being passed to the ledermann-rails-settings module.  At the moment they are saved immediately, regardless if the model validation has actually fired - I can see through script/console that validation errors are being raised.

### Example

For instance I would like to validate that the attribute :foo is within the range of 0..100 for decimal usage (or even a regex).  I've found that with the previous post that I can use standard Rails validators (surprise, surprise) but I want to halt on actually saving any values until those are addressed - ensure that the user of the GUI has given 61.43 as a numerical value.

The following code has been borrowed from the quoted post.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_settings

  validates_inclusion_of :foo, :in => 0..100

  def self.settings_attr_accessor(*args)

    >>SOME SORT OF UNLESS MODEL.VALID? CHECK HERE      

      args.each do |method_name|
        eval "
          def #{method_name}
            self.settings.send(:#{method_name})
          end
          def #{method_name}=(value)
            self.settings.send(:#{method_name}=, value)
          end
        "
      end

    >>END UNLESS

  end

  settings_attr_accessor :foo

end
```

Anyone have any thoughts here on pulling the state of the model at this point outside of having to put this into a before filter?  The goal here is to be able to use the standard validations and avoid rolling custom validation checks for each new settings_attr_accessor that is added.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a newer version that works in the new 2x syntax.  Yes it is ugly and does double eval.
This produces namespaces method names and adds them to the attr_accessible list.  The names are in the form of `"#{namespace}_#{attribute}` and can be use in forms. I am monkeying with a ppatch to the gem to do this automatically but I an not there yet.

```
has_settings do |s|
  eval 'def self.settings_accessors(namespace, defaults)
        defaults.keys.each do |method_name|
        attr_accessible "#{namespace}_#{method_name}"
        eval "def #{namespace}_#{method_name}
                self.settings(:#{namespace.to_s}).send(:#{method_name})
              end
              def #{namespace}_#{method_name}=(value)
                self.settings(:#{namespace}).send(:#{method_name}=, value)
              end
            "
        end
      end'
  namespace = :fileshare
  defaults = {:media => false, :sit => false, :quota_size => 1}
  s.key namespace, :defaults => defaults
  self.settings_accessors(namespace, defaults)
end
```