# How to set user preferences from a view when using the rails-setting gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've go the rails-settings (https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings) gem to work on the command line, but have no idea how to set the values through a view. How should I go about this?

This answer here: [How to create a form for the rails-settings plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425798/how-to-create-a-form-for-the-rails-settings-plugin) isn't working for me as I think it is for an old version of the gem/version of rails.